# Does liferay 7.2 support websockets?

Tags: websocket, liferay, liferay-7

Im trying to create a angular portlet that communicates with the portal via websockets. For Liferay 7.0 I found [this tutorial](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/liferay-websocket-whiteboard) but I couldn't get it to work on 7.2 and I can't find anything on websockets for 7.2.

Is it possible to do the same in Liferay Portal CE 7.2 or is that no longer supported?

Comment: I would assume that it is .. so what's your issue ?

Comment: @André i just followed the tutorial but Im not sure how to do all the steps in 7.2 and i get an error that the url cannot be deployed to because an endpoint is already registered there. but when i try to connect to the url i get a 404 error.

Comment: I have followed the same tutorial for 7.3 and it worked without any issues.